# $\mathbb{E}(X_{Y+1}X_{2}^{2}X_{2}|x_{1})$ with $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y\sim Pois(1)$ both independent

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, expected-value

Let $\{X_{i},i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a sequence of independent standard normal random variables. Furthermore, $Y$ is a Poisson distributed random variable with parameter $\lambda=1$, i.e., $\mathbb{P}(Y=n)=\frac{e^{-1}}{n!}, n=0,1,2,...$, and Y is independent of the sequence $\{X_{i},i\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Compute the following (conditional) expectation
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_{Y+1}X_{1}^{2}X_{2}|X_{1})
$$

Comment: Can your show your attempt?

Comment: Knowing, $X_{1}$ it is possible to take out $X_{1}^{2}$. Using the property of conditional expectation, we can condition on Y, which gives $\mathbb{E}(X_{Y+1}X_{1}^{2}X_{2}|X_{1})=X_{1}^{2}\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X_{2}X_{Y+1}|Y))$. Now, we are able to use the distribution of $Y$ and the fact that $Y$ is independent of sequence $\{X_{i},i\in\mathbb{N}\}$, since for $Y\neq1$ with probability $1-e^{-1}$ we have $\mathbb{E}(X_{2}X_{Y+1})=0$. We may conclude that $\mathbb{E}(X_{Y+1}X_{1}^{2}X_{2}|X_{1})=X_{1}^{2}(e^{-1}(1)+(1-e^{-1})(0))$, this was my attempt.

Comment: Congratulations! You have answered the question yourselves.

Comment: The $\lambda$ in Poisson distribution is supposed to be positive. It should be $\lambda=1$.

Comment: Thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[ X_{Y+1} X_1^2 X_2 | X_1 \right] = \mathbb{P}(Y=1) \mathbb{E} \left[ X_2X_1^2 X_2 | X_1 \right] + \mathbb{P} (Y\geq 2) \mathbb{E}\left[X_3X_1^2X_2 | X_1\right]\\ = \mathbb{P}(Y=1) \mathbb{E}[X_2^2] X_1^2 + \mathbb{P}(Y\geq 2) \mathbb{E}[X_2]^2 \cdot X_1^2
$$

And now you simply use the distribution of $Y$ and $X_i$...

Comment: Thanks, however that gives the same value

Comment: Should you be considering the possibility $Y=0$?